# How to implement the concept of particles entering an open network according to a Poisson process with a rate different from the rate in the network

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, poisson-process

[Poisson Process with different rates][1]
[Poisson Process with different rates][2]

! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJ87x.png

![2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJsB4.png

How do I choose if the next poisson clock a particle is going to enter the network or go through the network?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: well, I am considering a node o' where it has infinite particles and it is sending with rate 1 to node o particles but after some particles are in the network i dont know how to implement and nick tick if a particle is gonna go from o' to o or one of  the particles of the netwoka re gonna move